# Postgresql - How to get numeric value from the end of string and string without end numeric value

Tags: regex, string, postgresql, trim, numeric

I have the following usernames in Postgresql user table.

```
**username**
test
123test
123test456
test123
test45test
test55test55
```

So I am trying to get the string without end numeric value and end numeric value seperately.

I am expecting following output

```
str          num
----------------
test         0
123test      0
123test      456
test         123
test45test   0
test55test   55
```

How to write a Postgresql query that will return the above result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `regexp_replace()` and `substring()`:

```
select
    regexp_replace(username, '\d+$', '') str,
    coalesce(substring(username from '\d+$')::int, 0) num
from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=be9e61afd3c026424ca2119db67cf99c)**:

```
with mytable as (
    select 'test' username
    union all select '123test'
    union all select '123test456'
    union all select 'test123'
    union all select 'test45test'
    union all select 'test55test55'
)
select
    regexp_replace(username, '\d+$', '') str,
    coalesce(substring(username from '\d+$')::int, 0) num
from mytable
```

```
str        | num
:--------- | --:
test       |   0
123test    |   0
123test    | 456
test       | 123
test45test |   0
test55test |  55
```